# Summablity and countability

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A$ be an infinite set. For each $a \in A$, let $x_a$ be a non-negative number. Let the value of the series $\sum_{a \in A} x_a$ be the value of the supremum of its finite partial sums, i.e.:
>
> $$\sum_{a \in A} x_a = \sup_{n \geq 0} \sup_{(a_1, \ldots , a_n) \subset A} \left(x_{a_1} + x_{a_1} + \ldots + x_{a_n}\right)$$
>   (Supremum is well defined even when its value is infinite)
>
> If $\sum_{a \in A} {x_a}$ is finite, prove that the set $A' = \left\{{a \in A | a > 0}\right\}$
>   is countable.

My guess is that we have to write $A$ as a union of finitely many sets.

Comment: (Additionally, in the linked question, the problem is examined without any appeal to the axiom of choice. This makes the answer a bit more subtle, as a countable union of finite sets no longer needs to be countable.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I don't see how this could be a duplicate of that. This is about generalized sums; that's about some sort of ordinal-indexed series. Also, it's extremely unclear to me what this question is trying to ask.

Comment: @dfeuer The ordinals and what not are a distraction. The essential question being asked (and addressed in the answers) is "when is a series of positive terms finite?". (Of course, it may be that the recognition that the question is a duplicate only happens after one actually sees how to solve the current version, I am not advocating one way or the other.)

Comment: Right, I went through the question and its answer and don't really see how they are the same (partly because of my lack of knowledge as well).So I think even if they are more or less the same problem, this one deserves an answer as well. Also as @dfeuer also mentioned I don't understand what the question asks. For the two supremums, what does that mean? are we taking the supremum of the sum and then take the supremum over all such sums?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

How many $x_a$ can be greater than $1$? Than $\frac12$? Than $\frac13$? Formalise your observation by expressing $A'$ in a suitable way.

The same type of argument is used in *many* countability proofs. As such, it is an important part of your mathematical proof-toolbox.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! But I don't quite understand what you are trying to say. Aren't the $x_a's$ infinitely many? They are just positive numbers we assign to members of an infinite set, thus their numbers can also be infinite, so there are infinitely many of them greater than 1 and 1/2 and so on ... Or I am probably missing a trivial fact here.

Comment: @shm: A very weak form of the axiom of choice called the axiom of choice for countable sets of finite sets is equivalent to the statement that the union of countably many finite sets is countable. Can you see how that relates to Lord_Farin's hint?

Comment: @shm Is the given that the sum is finite compatible with infinitely many terms greater than 1?